# Best way to overwrite Azure Blob in Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

If I try to overwrite an existing blob:

```
blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, blob_name)
blob_client.upload_blob('Some text')
```

I get a `ResourceExistsError`.

I can check if the blob exists, delete it, and then upload it:

```
try:
    blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    blob_client.delete_blob()
except ResourceNotFoundError:
    pass
blob_client.upload_blob('Some text')
```

Taking into account both what the python azure blob storage API has available as well as idiomatic python style, is there a better way to overwrite the contents of an existing blob? I was expecting there to be some sort of overwrite parameter that could be optionally set to true in the `upload_blob` method, but it doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9076) it seems that you can add `overwrite=True` to `upload_blob` and it will work.

Comment: Would be nice if Microsoft documented their APIs!

Answer (score 2):

If you upload the blob with the same name and pass in the overwrite=True param, then all the contents of that file will be updated in place.

```
   blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

During the update readers will continue to see the old data by default.(until new data is committed).

I think there is also an option to read uncommitted data as well if readers wish to.

Below from the [docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.3.2/azure.storage.blob.html#azure.storage.blob.BlobClient.upload_blob):

> overwrite (bool) – Whether the blob to be uploaded should overwrite
> the current data. If True, upload_blob will overwrite the existing
> data. If set to False, the operation will fail with
> ResourceExistsError. The exception to the above is with Append blob
> types: if set to False and the data already exists, an error will not
> be raised and the data will be appended to the existing blob. If set
> overwrite=True, then the existing append blob will be deleted, and a
> new one created. Defaults to False.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer might work, but is potentially incorrect according to documentation;

`azure.storage.blob.ContainerClient.upload_blob()` can take the parameter `overwrite=True`
See [docs for ContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-upload-blob)

The documentation for
`azure.storage.blob.BlobClient.upload_blob()` does not document an `overwrite` parameter See [docs for BlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob)

Comment: Looks like it is mentioned in the docs now..